# Why does "Č" symbol makes my PDF completely weird?

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, jspdf

I use jsPDF in order to generate PDFs. When I use french or english letters, there is no problem. But once I use slovenian language, jsPDF generates weird PDF. I know it has to do with encoding, but I tried many and can't figure which one to take. Here are 2 pictures of what it looks like in english and in slovenian :

[image: English version PDF]
[image: Slovenian version PDF]

The english string is : *"Power cut"* and the slovenian string is : *"Izpad električne energije"*.
I think there is no need of my code here. I just have to understand how to correct the issue.

Comment: How do you put the string? To me, it seems you send a UTF-16 data, so with extra `0` which may be displayed as space. And also it caused the system to change font (so it may be a font setting problem: no font available with required metric, and so viewer may put wrong font with wrong metric in correct place for the original font, so it will show ugly)

Comment: This the exact part where I place the text : `doc.text(105, yPos + imgHeight + 15, $("#coupeconso-pdf").text(), { align: 'center' });`

After checking, the encoding is UTF-8. I will try to add a new font this afternoon, however, changing with the default jsPDF fonts didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reminder to self and others the behavior will be odd if not saving the HTML in an editor as UTF-8 with BOM (ByteOrderMark) , this tripped me up on a few tests.

The main instructions can be found at https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF#use-of-unicode-characters--utf-8

[image]

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang=pl>
      <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
      </head>
      <body>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.debug.js" integrity="sha384-NaWTHo/8YCBYJ59830LTz/P4aQZK1sS0SneOgAvhsIl3zBu8r9RevNg5lHCHAuQ/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
    var doc = new jsPDF({
      orientation: 'p',
      unit: 'mm',
      format: 'a4'
    })

    window.onload = function fontDemo() {
    const NotoSans = 'AAEAAAANAIAAAwBQR0RFRvDX3ecAA8DgAAAFwEdQT1OembooAAPGoAAA6hhHU1VCRDfqagAEsLgAABaAT1M
```

...
too long for a snippet
...

```
gEUARYBGAEaARwBHgEgASIBJAEmASgBKgEsAS4BMAEyATQBNgE4ATsBPQE/AUMBRQFHAUkB+gH8Af4CAAITAhQCFQNhC4ELgguDC4QLhQuGC4cLiAuJC4oLiwunAAEAAAABAAgAAgBCAB4J7wnwCfEJ8gnzCfQJ9Qn2CfcJ+AnvCfAJ8QnyCfMJ9An1CfYJ9wn4Ce8J8AnxCfIJ8wn0CfUJ9gn3CfgAAgADABMAHAAACfkKAgAKCgQKDQAUAAEAAAABAAgAAQAGAbwAAQABCtcAAQAAAAEACAABAAYJ8AABAAEAEw==';

    doc.addFileToVFS("NotoSans.ttf", NotoSans);
    doc.addFont("NotoSans.ttf", "NotoSans", "normal");
    doc.setFont("NotoSans");

    doc.setTextColor(0, 0, 1);
    doc.setFontSize(50);
    //  text, x, y, var, var, 'alignment'
    doc.text("Izpad električne energije", 105,  100, null, null, 'center');
    doc.save("Example.pdf");
    }
      </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

---

```
File: Example.pdf
Created: 7/25/2022
PDF Producer: jsPDF 1.5.3
PDF Version: 1.3
File Size: 69.79 KB (71,460 Bytes)
Number of Pages: 1
Page Size: 8.27 x 11.69 in (A4)
   
Fonts: Courier (Type1; Ansi)
Courier-Bold (Type1; Ansi)
Courier-BoldOblique (Type1; Ansi)
Courier-Oblique (Type1; Ansi)
Helvetica (Type1; Ansi)
Helvetica-Bold (Type1; Ansi)
Helvetica-BoldOblique (Type1; Ansi)
Helvetica-Oblique (Type1;
```

**NotoSans (TrueType (CID); Identity-H; embedded)**

```
Symbol (Type1)
Times-Bold (Type1; Ansi)
Times-BoldItalic (Type1; Ansi)
Times-Italic (Type1; Ansi)
Times-Roman (Type1; Ansi)
ZapfDingbats (Type1)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, that is what I did few days ago. Didn't have time to write solution to my own answer and was about to do so.